# Can Mvemba a Nzinga win religious victory?

Tags: civilization-6

Mvemba a Nzinga, the leader of the Kongo civ, has the following ability:

> ### Religious Convert
>
> May not build Holy Site Districts, gain Great Prophets, or found Religions. Gains all Beliefs of any Religion that has established itself in a majority of his cities. Recieves an Apostle each time he finishes a M'banza or Theater Square (of that city's majority Religion).

Does that mean it is impossible for this civ to win using religious victory?

Comment: I want to say yes, but it will be harder.

Comment: @TimmyJim Don't you need to found a religion to win religious victory though?

Comment: It is indeed impossible, and in fact this is the key point of a strategy to get the "win on deity" achievement without having to be good at the game - disable all victory conditions except for religious and play a duel against Mvemba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are correct. Unfortunately, because it would be hilariously awesome if it were possible, Mvemba a Nzinga cannot win a religious victory.

> In order to obtain a Religious Victory, you must make **your Religion** the predominant Religion for every other major civilization in the game.
>   - "Religious Victory", Civilopedia; emphasis added

I understand this to imply only the creators of a Religion are eligible for a Religious Victory condition. If Mvemba a Nzinga spreads the religion of his cities to other civilizations, he is helping the creator of that religion advance towards a Religious Victory, not himself.

Comment: Indeed, and even if you capture the holy city of an opponent and eliminate that opponent, you still do not appear as a candidate for a religion victory.